# Counting number of times value exceeded for a range of dates

Tags: excel, date, count, conditional-statements

I have a list of wave heights measured hourly for every day in a year. All I want to do is have Excel count if the wave height exceeds a certain value (say, 6m in height) just once for a given day - that is, if the data says the wave height was over 6m three times on one day, it will just count that as a single occurrence.

```
Date    Wave Height

1/1/98  1.99

1/1/98  2.16

1/1/98  2.21

1/1/98  6.50

1/1/98  6.71

1/1/98  2.27

1/1/98  2.31
```

In the above data set, I'd like the date 1/1/98 to have a "1" count since it exceeds 6m at least once, and I'd like this to continue all the way down for every date. 
I've been trying to use countifs equations, but haven't been able to get it to do quite what I want. 
This was the last one I tried: =COUNTIFS(H2:H8500,">=6",G2:G8500,"=$G2") where H is the  wave height column and G is the date column.
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Can you show the `countifs` you've used?

Comment: sure, just added it in an edit

Comment: If you just want to show a 1 if the count is greater than 1, why not wrap what you have in an `if-statement?` Like so: `=if(countifs(....) > 0, 1, 0)`.

Comment: part of my problem is that in trying to make the individual counts only pertain to one day at a time, I can't seem to make the reference date cell move to the next date once it's counted occurences for the previous date

Comment: You could have your comparison date stored in cell `G1` and just change it when you want to compare to a new date, such as in =if(countifs(....., "=$G$1"), ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would work like this:

first assign your LIMIT (6m) value to a cell as a general constant, since it may change in the future. This way you can change this value wherever it is being used (update all formulas).  In our case this constant lies on cell B1 (thus the static reference $B$1 in the formulas).

Then I would layout my data like in this example sheet I set up:

[image]

There are 24 columns, one for every measurement in a single day, since they are taken hourly. I calculate whether there is a single limit hit throughout the day (once in a row) using the following formula (example for date 1/1/1998 on row 4):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(O4:Y4; ">" & $B$1) >= 1; TRUE; FALSE)
```

We complete the sequence for every date (row) in our datasheet.

At the bottom we include a cell with the value period hits which counts the number of "TRUE" values like this:

```
=COUNTIF(AA4:AA13; TRUE)
```

I broke down the calculation in 2-steps since holding a huge expression with multiple COUNTIFS ranges associated, is not a viable solution in such cases.

I hope I interpreted correctly your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

With over 8,000 readings each year I think a PivotTable might be useful, if not for exactly the requirement you mention. Say in I1 insert your cut-off value (`6`) and in B2 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(H2>I$1,1,"")
```

This is just to identify the entries exceeding your chosen cut-off.

Create a PT with FILTERS `6`, ROWS `Date` and Max of `Wave Height` for Σ VALUES. Add a Calculated field to it, say named `Qcount`, with Formula:

```
=COUNT('6')
```

For this Summarize value field by Count and Show Values as Running Total In Date.

Apply the PT filter to select `1` and you should have a column (`Count of Qcount`) where the bottom entry is the result you seek, but where the rest of the PT shows (a) the maximum wave height for the period (b) the maximum wave height for each day that exceeded your chosen limit and (c) a listing of the days when the limit was exceeded. Drill down should also be possible.

This does rely upon the dates and times being separate (distinct cells - not a date/time combination).